# Magento2 Why I can't get POST data from .\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request?

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer

### This is my code in my module observer

```
namespace Customtest\Customlogin\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{


     protected $_request;

  public function __construct(

      \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request


  ) {

      $this->_request = $request;

  }
  public function execute(Observer $observer) {

            $post = $this->_request->getPost('login');

            var_dump($post) ;

  }

}
```

This code is work in localhost but when I upload to live server,  Browser

show  "`http error 500`"

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Customtest\Customlogin\Observer\CustomerLogin::__construct() must
>   implement interface Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface, instance
>   of Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory given, called in
>   /opt/stack/magento2/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 111 and defined in
>   /opt/stack/magento2/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/Customtest\Customlogin/Observer/CustomerLogin.php:15
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /opt/stack/magento2/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   Customtest\Customlogin\Observer\CustomerLogin->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Url)) #1
>   /opt/stack/magento2/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Customtest\Hello...',
>   Array) #2
>   /opt/stack/magento2/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Obj
>   in
>   /opt/stack/magento2/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/Customtest\Customlogin/Observer/CustomerLogin.php
>   on line 15

Comment: I have updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```